# Colon(:) operator in Unix shell

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-script

As far as colon is concerned i understand that is is used in certain situations as a null and as a parameter of expansion for substring, but can someone explain me this:

```
do_qc: $(STAGE1_OUT_FILES)
```

More examples:

```
print_stage0_files: setup_dirs
  $(info * $(SETUP_DATA_FILES))
```

Or

```
quality_filtering: setup $(STAGE1_OUT_FILES)
  $(call p_info,[DONE] Quality filtering)
```

Shebang of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: Looks like a Makefile.

Comment: i don't really know since it is in the middle of a shell script, furthermore in another example of it in the same script a function is executed:

[`quality_filtering: setup $(STAGE1_OUT_FILES) ` ]  [`$(call p_info,[DONE] Quality filtering)` ]

Comment: Please, show the shebang line of the script, and some more examples. Also, update the question, don't post code to comments. `$(call ` is definitely a Makefile syntax.

Comment: If it's in the middle of the script and the shebang is as written, then most probably it's a shell script with an inlined makefile.

Comment: Yeah, from what i've been searching you seem to be completely right. Thanks for your help i wasn't really seeing that possibility :)

Comment: Can we see the full script? Also, do we know that this script is actually executed and not actually parsed by another script?